# Rellenar DropDownList con consulta SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp, dropdownlist

estoy desesperado con este problema.
Tengo un dropdownlist en un proyecto y no consigo que me muestre los datos para guardar el seleccionado. Me explico, ese DDL mostrará una serie de proyectos y deseo que el usuario seleccione uno, guarde el valor para luego insertarlo en una SQL. Los proyectos vienen de una tabla (Proyectos) de SQL.
Adjunto el código que tengo hecho.
¿Podréis ayudarme?

Si algo no queda suficientemente claro no dudéis en poner preguntas ya que estoy empezando a publicar mis preguntas y estoy aprendiendo.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    cargardatos();
    }
        private void cargadatos()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (eleccionproyecto())
                {
                    cargarControl();
                }
            }
        }
        private bool eleccionproyecto()
        {
            int eleccion = 0;
            bool valorproyectos = false;
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Empresas WHERE Empresa = '" + Session["Empresa"]+ "'";
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaConexion2"].ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter daAdaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    SqlDataReader lector = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (lector.Read())
                    {
                        eleccion = Convert.ToInt32(lector["Proyectos"]);
                    }
                    daAdaptador.Fill(datatable);
                }
                conn.Close();
                if (eleccion == 1)
                {
                    valorproyectos = true;
                }
            }
                return valorproyectos; 
        }
        private DataSet ConsultarProyecto()
        { 
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaConexion2"].ToString()))
        {
            DataSet datatable = new DataSet();
            string cmd = "";
            cmd = "select CODIGO, DESCRIPCION from PRJAWMA";
                try
                {

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter daAdaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
                    daAdaptador.Fill(datatable, "PRJAWMA");
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
                return datatable;
            }

        }
        public void cargarControl()
        {
            try
            {
                dropDownList.DataSource = ConsultarProyecto();
                dropDownList.DataTextField = "DESCRIPCION";
                dropDownList.DataValueField = "CODIGO";
                dropDownList.DataBind();
                dropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Seleccione un proyecto", "0"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        protected void ProyectoSeleccionado(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ProyectoID = Convert.ToInt32(dropDownList.SelectedValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaciones, usar Entity Framework o algun ORM (Object-Relationship Mapping) para evitar usar DataTable y construir tus consultas a mano, pero ASP.NET WebForms está diseñado para tener caminos efectivos de poder trabajar con la capa de datos.

Para este tipo de consultas generales podes usar la infraestructura que ya te provee ASP.NET, todavía hay mejores opciones si usas objetos específicos, desde .NET 4, pero para el caso podes aprovechar un SqlDataSource que te va a brindar la lógica para conectarte a la base de datos, solo especificando tu consulta SQL y un ConnectionString binder podes facilitar a que base de datos se va a conectar. El control DropDownList se encargará de hacer el trabajo de buscar el DataSourceID que se le especifica.

Que vas a hacer con los datos ya es otra historia, pero en el siguiente ejemplo se define un DataSource con Nombre 'DSEmpresas', y un control UXEmpresa, que vas a poder acceder desde el Code Behind, para obtener el dato seleccionado, cuando se haga el Post Back.

Veo que estas jalando datos de la Empresa para validar que hay una empresa en la base de datos, pero no le pasas ningun parametro a la siguiente consulta a PRJAWMA, te recomendaría un camino más corto para validar la empresa:

En el code behind podes tener una propiedad o campo que va a ayudar a mostrar u ocultar el DropDownList, para no construirlo a mano.

```
protected bool eleccion;
```

Para el Page_OnLoad:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaConexion2"].ToString()))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Proyectos FROM Empresas WHERE Empresa = @NombreEmpresa", conn);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NombreEmpresa", Session["Empresa"]));
    conn.Open();
    int proyectos = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    eleccion = proyectos == 1;
}
```

```
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="UXProyecto" DataSourceID="DSProyectos" DataTextField="DESCRIPCION" DataValueField="CODIGO" Visible='<%# this.eleccion %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="DSProyectos" SelectCommand="select CODIGO, DESCRIPCION from PRJAWMA" SelectCommandType="Text" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cadenaConexion2 %>">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```